# share video to line app

Tags: android, line

I want to share video file to Line app from my app.
In android 6.0 and 7.0
I can use following code to share.

```
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fileFull);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("video/mp4");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.sharevideoto)));
```

But the new android 8.0 need use fileprovider

```
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PlayvideoActivity.this, 
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",fileFull);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("video/mp4");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.sharevideoto)));
```

But Line app will show error when use fileprovider to share video.
But using fileprovider share picture is work.

Comment: Hello. Can you tell me please, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

for Kotlin

```
fun onShareVideo(uri: Uri, packageNameOfApp: String) {
val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
share.type = "video/*"
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
share.setPackage(packageNameOfApp) //change packageNameOfApp to jp.naver.line.android
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"))
}
```

NOTE

```
You can use code above for twitter, instagram, gmail...
```

It worked good for all version.